# Jquery slider change to perform a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to perform a calculation and set an input value when the slider is moved. I can't get it to work, any help much appreciated. please see my code below:

```
if (modalContentCall[objname].private_use == true) {
    $(this).append($('<div>').load('Content_for_injection.htm #private_use',function(){
            $('#inputamount').change(function() {
            var isinputamount = parseInt($('#inputamount').val());

            });                 
               $( "#slider-range-max" ).slider({
                range: "max",
                min: 0,
                max: 100,
                value: 0,
                slide: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#slideramount" ).val( ui.value );
                if (isinputamount > 0) {
                $( "#actualamount" ).val( ui.value/100*isinputamount );                 
                }
                else $( "#actualamount" ).val(0);
               }
});
$( "#slideramount" ).val( $( "#slider-range-max" ).slider( "value" ) );
$( "#actualamount" ).val( $( "#slider-range-max" ).slider( "value" ) );
```

Most of this code is standard UI code and works fine. I have added:

```
if (isinputamount > 0) {
                    $( "#actualamount" ).val( ui.value/100*isinputamount );                 
                    }
                    else $( "#actualamount" ).val(0);
                   }
```

and:

```
$( "#actualamount" ).val( $( "#slider-range-max" ).slider( "value" ) );
```

I want to take the input added to `#inputamount` multiply by the slider value (when this is moved) divided by 100 (to get a percentage decimal 1/100) to give a resulting number in `#actualamount`.

I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Can you provide more details about how your code doesn't work?  Does it produce any effect?  Does it throw an error?  Can you tell where it breaks down?

Comment: Console is telling me isinputamount in the if statement is not defined. I removed the var when setting the variable to make it global but still no good. A zero is displayed in the #actualamount input box where I had hoped for a number and my code seems to stop the slider button moving along its path but will allow the range output to work. Cheers for any help A

Comment: Well, `isinputamount` is only defined when the value of `#inputamount` changes.  Are you changing `#inputamount`?

Comment: Thanks ASGM for taking the time to help out. It was the global variable that solved it, not sure why it didn't work 1st time but works fine now.

Comment: Great!  You can post your own answer to your question and accept it, so other people can see that your problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was solved by using a global variable, I changed the 4th line of code in my question from this

```
var isinputamount = parseInt($('#inputamount').val());
```

to this

```
window.isinputamount = parseInt($('#inputamount').val());
```

It now works fine.